# Ubuntu Boots Up in Emergency Mode and I'm Too Much of a Potato to Diagnose

Tags: boot

My computer froze and I foolishly did a hard reset. Now when I try to boot Ubuntu, it stalls on the loading screen for about 30 seconds and then kicks me into emergency mode. I've taken a look at the journal and I'd gladly post the revelant results here but there are hundreds of lines and I'm not sure which parts to post. I'll update this if/when someone guides me to it.

Thanks. :)

EDIT:

here are some highlighted/red sections that seemed like they'd be relevant:

```
secureboot: Secure boot could not be determined (mode 0)

ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): Optiional FADT field Pm2ControlBlock has valid Length but zero address: (long string)

xhci_hcd 0000:4:00.0: host halt failed, -110

|| : can't setup: -110
|| : init 0000:4:00.0 fail, -110
Timed out waiting for device on dev-disk-by\(long string).device.
```

Comment: Please execute the command `journalctl -b -p 3`, and paste the output of that command into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`